# Could not get unknown property 'src' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project. on Ubuntu

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ubuntu-18.04

I'm getting this error during build process on Ubuntu 18.04 VPS.
4 Core CPU 16GB RAM 
Ubuntu 18.04 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
Gradle version gradle-3.3

**Stacktrace**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/var/data/www/app/app/build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'src' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property 'src' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getMissingProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:85)
        at org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject.getProperty(AbstractDynamicObject.java:62)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.propertyMissing(BasicScript.java:70)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.Script.getProperty(Script.java:56)
        at build_i626zl2r19gg7mw925f99hom.run(/var/data/www/app/app/build.gradle:1)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:90)
        ... 62 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 0.838 secs
```